# Getting flycheck "jump to next/previous error" to cycle

Tags: flycheck

I'd like M-g n and M-g p to cycle, at least when I'm using them with flycheck. This feature requires writing a custom function as it's not supported (as mentioned on https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/64 and confirmed in chat), but I am an Elisp noob.

For other reasons (working around https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/issues/268), in `flycheck-mode` I bypass `next-error` and invoke `flycheck-next-error` directly. I can live with normal compilation mode not cycling since I use it seldom (though probably this will get annoying if I do start using compilation mode).

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I came up with (as a noob) after learning about `condition-case`, advices, `universal-argument` and some internals of flycheck. I usually don't write code with so little clue of what I'm doing, so I welcome better answers.

Commented out logging is left in since I don't regard this as finished, and for those who'd like to trace execution of this code.

Finally, this does nothing for raw `next-error`, it is only invoked when flycheck is.

```el
;; Optional: ensure flycheck cycles, both when going backward and forward.
;; Tries to handle arguments correctly.
;; Since flycheck-previous-error is written in terms of flycheck-next-error,
;; advising the latter is enough.
(defun flycheck-next-error-loop-advice (orig-fun &optional n reset)
  ; (message "flycheck-next-error called with args %S %S" n reset)
  (condition-case err
      (apply orig-fun (list n reset))
    ((user-error)
     (let ((error-count (length flycheck-current-errors)))
       (if (and
            (> error-count 0)                   ; There are errors so we can cycle.
            (equal (error-message-string err) "No more Flycheck errors"))
           ;; We need to cycle.
           (let* ((req-n (if (numberp n) n 1)) ; Requested displacement.
                  ; An universal argument is taken as reset, so shouldn't fail.
                  (curr-pos (if (> req-n 0) (- error-count 1) 0)) ; 0-indexed.
                  (next-pos (mod (+ curr-pos req-n) error-count))) ; next-pos must be 1-indexed
             ; (message "error-count %S; req-n %S; curr-pos %S; next-pos %S" error-count req-n curr-pos next-pos)
             ; orig-fun is flycheck-next-error (but without advise)
             ; Argument to flycheck-next-error must be 1-based.
             (apply orig-fun (list (+ 1 next-pos) 'reset)))
         (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))))

(advice-add 'flycheck-next-error :around #'flycheck-next-error-loop-advice)
```

This is a snapshot of https://gist.github.com/Blaisorblade/c7349438b06e7b1e034db775408ac4cb, where I'll place any updated version.

Comment: Works like a magic!