# How to apply flycheck right after a new file is opened

Tags: python, flycheck

I am using flycheck for for Python. I want `flycheck` to detect any errors right away when any Python file is opened. Currently it can detect if there is a modification and save operation is performed.

Let's say I have following code in `hello.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

print(os.getpid())
```

Than I have commented out `print(os.getpid())` and close the file and reopened it. At this stage flycheck does not detect that `'os' imported but unused [F401]`. I have to make some moditifications and save the file for it do detect it.

---

my setup:

```
(require 'flycheck)
(require 'flycheck-mypy)

(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3"
      python-shell-prompt-detect-failure-warning nil
      flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "python3"
      python-shell-completion-native-enable nil
      python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters '("python3")
      elpy-shell-echo-output nil ; 
      )

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; (setq flycheck-mypyrc "~/venv/bin/pylint")
        (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/venv/bin/pylint")
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-b") 'break-point)
        (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.pylintrc")))
```

I am also using [Getting flycheck “jump to next/previous error” to cycle](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27511/18414), it won't also able to detect it till save is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
(setq flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(save idle-buffer-switch idle-change new-line mode-enabled)
      flycheck-idle-buffer-switch-delay 0)
```

This tells `flycheck` to run immediately "after you switch to a buffer". The other choices like `save`, `idle-change`, `new-line`, and `mode-enabled` are already configured as the default choices. The second option reduces the delay before the check is triggered. There is also `flycheck-idle-change-delay` which you can reduce if you want.

Comment: What would be the smallest value I can reduce for `flycheck-idle-change-delay` ? or is there any recommended value for it?

Comment: The default value is `0.5`, you can make it `0`.

Comment: Sorry for late response but I observe that if the buffer is not saved this does not help

Comment: Sorry for late response, would it be wise to keep `(setq flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(save mode-enable))` setting as well?